# SVD and non-negative matrix factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

The SVD and NMF are seem to be very close, so the question: how can I obtain NMF of given matrix from its SVD decomposition?

I've tried to zero-in all negative parts of SVD decomposition, but this gives bad results and iterative approach (zero-in, correct, zero-in) does not help either. Am I missing something or there is no meaningful relation between SVD and NMF?

Comment: read the NMF paper http://papers.nips.cc/paper/1861-algorithms-for-non-negative-matrix-factorization.pdf and a course on the SVD (or PCA for the minimization approach), you'll see they are completely different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good reference explaining the relation between PCA and NMF
[Same author suggested by reuns but with more interpretation](http://www.columbia.edu/~jwp2128/Teaching/E4903/papers/nmf_nature.pdf)

I have found some work done by Chris Ding showing relation between PCA to Clustering. Where PCA is clustering data based on variances while one type of clustering called K-means which cluster the data based on Euclidean Distances. From this point there are proves showing the relation between K-means clustering to NMF.

[Brief ppt showing relation between formulas](https://web.stanford.edu/group/mmds/slides/ding-mmds.pdf)

[Good Reference to start with](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.75.3933&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[If the previous one is hard this is having a brief of it](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/11/Papers/261.pdf)

Comment: Really nice references. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Could you please update second reference (the link is broken).

Comment: @Moonwalker done